# Generate PDF from JPanel Components

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

I am developing a java application, and have sort of "working" JLayeredPanel in a scrollPanel, where I add some JLabels on! (something like working on Word). I want to get all the components from the layeredPanel and get a PDF file.

What I have, is get an Image from the layeredPanel, and then generate the PDF with iTextPdf of that image, but I don't get the resolution I want/need.

```
public void printToPDF(java.awt.Image awtImage, String fileName) {
            try {

                    Document d = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream(fileName));
                    d.open();

                    Image iTextImage = Image.getInstance(writer, awtImage, 1);

                    iTextImage.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                    iTextImage.scaleToFit(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
                    d.add(iTextImage);

                    d.close();
            }
    }
```

I need to run through all the components of the layeredPane adding them separately to `d` to get a real resolution of the JLabel's text and not an image version of it.

I am using iTextPDF v5.5.12

**EDIT 2:**

Saving the image before generating the PDF I get the same resolution as on Screen "working area".

Generating the PDF with that Image, I have:

1. Generate with `scaleToFit(PageSize.A4)` -> it gets pixelated;
2. Generate without `scaleToFit(PageSize.A4)`-> it gets oversized, and when resizing to A4 -> it gets pixelated; (Supposedly the original image is already A4 size!)

Conluding, I have to possible Solutions

1. Keep the Original Image file only;
2. Try to generate the PDF in other way. 
   Something like this: [Example of PDF - text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU5qe.png) (this is Text so it maintains resolution);

Instead of having this: [Example of PDF - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdtCv.png) (this is not Text, it's image, so it pixelates)

I'd prefer this one so I could avoid some CMYK problems on printing the final file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], go through the [help], read [ask] and post a proper [mcve] that shows what you've tried and a link to an image showing your problem and the expected result. Also specify which version of `iText` you're using as well

Comment: Thanks @Frakcool . I have just edited the question.

Comment: You didn't even read the links I provided, put special attention to [Minimal, **Complete** and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You haven't read the 1st link I posted though...

Comment: `but I don't get the resolution I want/need.` - when you get an image of a component, you get the resolution of the screen you are using. I have no idea what iTextPDF does with this image.

Comment: @camickr while the program is running, the text, for example, is very clear, but after the image is generated, the resultant text is pixelated! And the result is the same size of the one I have on de Panel.

Comment: @Anonirato, so is the problem with you Swing code to create the image, or the iTextPDF processing??? Create the image you want and display it on a JLabel to see if you have the same quality as the frame. If so then you know the problem is iText. I would guess the problem is that you are using `scaleToFit()`. If this causes the image size to be increased then of course it will be pixelated. Don't use the method. Try creating the PDF with the image at its original size.

Comment: @camickr, the iTextPDF has no problem... I removed `scaleToFit()` , and the result is better, you were right! But I still need "quality printing"... (This is supposed to do something like flyers automatically - all with the same template - and then print them). 
For iTextPDF, I wanted to generate the PDF  with the components individualy, so the `JLabels`  remained "text" and so I wouldn't loose resolution.

Comment: I already told you that you don't lose resolution when using Swing to create an image of a component. You haven't posted your `Minimal Example` yet so there is nothing we can do to help.